# Change space between abstract title and abstract body?

Tags: spacing, abstract

How do I change the spacing between the abstract title/name and the abstract body/text?

```
\documentclass{article}
\author{\normalsize Author}
\title{Title}
\date{\normalsize \today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}\normalsize Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec id nibh nec ipsum sagittis venenatis. Vivamus mollis pulvinar justo. Phasellus vel ligula eget elit blandit mattis a vel mi. Maecenas luctus lobortis accumsan. Integer vel ultrices urna. Ut sit amet lorem luctus purus fringilla sollicitudin. Sed ante mi, aliquam eget nulla eget, ultricies rutrum orci. In libero sapien, lacinia eu erat quis, gravida sollicitudin orci. Morbi eu fermentum magna. Duis vel metus condimentum purus feugiat interdum tincidunt ut tortor. Etiam volutpat dapibus mattis. 
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using? What do you use to create your abstract... `\begin{abstract}`...`\end{abstract}`...?

Comment: It's hard to help you if we don't know what you are doing. Can you please post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Of course. Here you go.

Answer (score 2):

`\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Abstract\vspace{0.2\textheight}}`

Answer (score 2):

The standard environment adds a negative spacing of -0.5em between the abstract title and the text (because it uses `center`).

You can easily adjust it to your likings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\abstract}{-.5em}{0em}{}{}

\begin{document}

\author{Author}
\title{Title}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Donec id nibh nec ipsum sagittis venenatis. Vivamus mollis
pulvinar justo. Phasellus vel ligula eget elit blandit
mattis a vel mi. Maecenas luctus lobortis accumsan. Integer
vel ultrices urna. Ut sit amet lorem luctus purus fringilla
sollicitudin. Sed ante mi, aliquam eget nulla eget, ultricies
rutrum orci. In libero sapien, lacinia eu erat quis, gravida
sollicitudin orci. Morbi eu fermentum magna. Duis vel metus
condimentum purus feugiat interdum tincidunt ut tortor.
Etiam volutpat dapibus mattis.
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

With `0em` the negative space doesn't get inserted, but no positive space either. Adjust the value until you're satisfied.

Note. Avoid plaguing your code with explicit `\normalsize` declarations. For instance, your code will make the abstract title smaller than the text. In order to get normal size, add

```
\patchcmd{\abstract}{\small}{\normalsize}{}{}
```